# Load optimized scripts on production server and non optimized during development using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

How to tell require.js to **load optimized files** instead of non optimized JavaScript files when the project is run **on production server**. Is it achievable using require configuration file. I mean **without replacing content of /js** folder or changing data-main reference in script tag?

EDIT:
Finally I used server side template variable to decide which JS directory to use

```
<script data-main="/{{jsMain}}/main" 
        src="/{{jsMain}}/libs/require/require.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I achieved it by checking the host with PHP and then changing the JS path. If that is an option to you I can expand with a proper answer

Comment: Either way, you'll have to run the optimizer to produce the optimized files. If you load your config from a file, you could use some sort of sniff to load the built file instead.

Comment: There is no configuration option for something like that. Is server side cooperation acceptable in your use case? If so, what is your server side platform?